# Get object with specify id from list object in APEX

Tags: apex, validation-rule, list, object

I have a list like following:

```
List<idName> = [idName:[name='AAA', id=1], 
            idName:[name='BBB', id=2],
            idName:[name='CCC', id=3]]
```

And one input is equal 2;
So how can I get object have id = 2 in this list with this input in APEX that not use FOR loop?

Please help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Is this APEX code? If so, please include it in the right format and as a complete piece of code. It's really hard assessing what you are asking like it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to create `Map<String, idName>` and populate it where key will be your `id` values. After that you can get any idName without for loop

Comment: Thanks @ytiq so much. That's great, it's working!

Comment: glad I could help